# How to create a button that sets a node value

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, rules, flags

I would like to create a set of buttons or text links on my site that set the value of a node field and/or create additional nodes.  Currently, I am using a combination of flags and rules to do this (when a flag is set, do the following...) This works fine, but it feels a bit cumbersome.  The flag has no other purpose other than triggering an action.  Is there a module specifically for doing this (including ajax) or is there another simpler way to perform this activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Field Button](https://drupal.org/project/button_field) module that creates and renders a button.  You can then write a rule that is triggered by button clicks.  This works great if you only need one or two buttons on a page.  However, this module has trouble figuring out which node the button belongs to (and therefor may not be a good option for lists of nodes & buttons rendered by views.)

Another option is the [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) module.  This module does roughly the same thing.  It  is not as pretty, but it has better rule integration.